# Redux reducer unit test

Tags: unit-testing, redux, mocha.js

And I'm trying to make unit-test for redux reducer. But i'm struggling with receiving the same expected and equal results.

```
const initState = {};

export default function (state = initState, action) {
  const newState = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {

    case CREATE_TYPE:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.customType.id]: {
          ...action.customType
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My test. Seems that problem in `customType: { id: 'test-id' }`

```
describe('reducer', () => {
  it('should return the initial state', () => {
    const state = reducer(undefined, { type: 'unknown' });
    expect(state).toEqual({});
  });

  it('should handle CREATE_TYPE', () => {
    expect(reducer({ test: true }, {
      type: CREATE_TYPE,
      customType: { id: 'test-id' },
      id: 'test-id'
    })).toEqual({
      'test-id': 'test-type',
      'test': true
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often it helps to spell everything out.

That way you can clearly understand what your expected outcome needs to be.

```
it('should handle CREATE_TYPE', () => {
  const initialState = { test: true };
  const customType = { id: 'test-id' };
  const action = {
    type: CREATE_TYPE,
    customType: customType,
    id: customType.id
  };
  const result = reducer(initialState, action);
  const expectedResult = {
    test: true,
    [customType.id]: customType
  };
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

It then becomes easier to see exactly where the issue lies.

Comment: Actually,I am getting reducer is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You are exprecting back from your reducer :

```
{
    ...state,
    [action.customType.id]: {
      ...action.customType
}
```

which if you send

```
{
  type: CREATE_TYPE,
  customType: { id: 'test-id' },
  id: 'test-id'
}
```

Will equate itself to :

```
{
   ...state,
   'test-id' : { id: 'test-id' }
}
```

and you are evaluating it equal to

```
{
 ...state,
'test-id': 'test-type'
}
```

I don't know how you are expecting to format your state via your reducer - but the way your reducer is set up now will not provide the state you are expecting. I don't know what you are expecting because i don't see the node or value 'test-type' anywhere else in your provided code. It looks like you just have some syntactical errors maybe?